# How to show upload progress of json data in axios, XMLHttpRequest, fetch?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I'm trying to upload json data server in react-native. But the problem is, json data contain `base64` image string. And I need display progress.
I tried like this, but it did not worked.

```js
function handleEvent(e) {
    setProgress((e.loaded / e.total) * 100)
}

function addListeners(xhr) {
    xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', handleEvent)
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
addListeners(xhr);
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
    };
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
```

and using axios

```js
var res = await axios.post(BASE_URL + '/crossstorage_addfile', payload, {
      headers, onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
        var percentCompleted =  Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total)
        console.log(percentCompleted)
      }
});
```

But nothing worked. Anything I can do resolve?
thank you.